# Background Worker with progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I am trying to get a `ProgressBar` with the progress of a dataset being converted to Excel using the `BackgroundWorker`. The problem is that the work is being done in a different class than the `ProgressBar` and I am having difficulty calling `worker.ReportProgress(...)` from within my loop. I am sorry if this is a easy thing but I am new to C# and have been trying this the whole day and just can't seem to get it right. Your help would be HIGHLY appreciated.

```
namespace CLT
{
    public partial class GenBulkReceipts : UserControl
    {
        private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            try
            {
                OpenFile();
            }

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
        private void OpenFile()

        {
            if (dsEx1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(dsEx1);
            }
        }

        public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            DataSet ImportDataSet = e.Argument as DataSet;
            AccountsToBeImported = new BLLService().Get_AccountsToBeReceipted(ImportDataSet);
        }

        public void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        // ...
    }
}

namespace BLL
{
    class GenBulkReceiptsBLL
    {
        public DataSet Get_AccountsToBeReceipted(DataSet dsImport)
        {
            DataSet dsReturn = AccountsDAL.QGenReceiptAccounts(0,0,"");//Kry Skoon DataSet wat ge-populate moet word

            CLT.GenBulkReceipts pb = new CLT.GenBulkReceipts();
            int TotalRows = dsImport.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            //pb.LoadProgressBar(TotalRows);
            int calc = 1;
            int ProgressPercentage;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dsImport.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
               ProgressPercentage = (calc / TotalRows) * 100;

                //This is the problem as I need to let my Progressbar progress here but I am not sure how
                //pb.worker.ReportProgress(ProgressPercentage);
            }

            return dsReturn;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `catch` clause of your `try-catch` located in the `btnOpen_Click(...)` method?

Comment: Please make sure you accept an answer if it lead to the resolution of your issue; and up vote any that you found useful.

Comment: It is there I just did not include it here to make the code sample sorter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `GenBulkReceiptsBLL` needs some reference to the `BackgroundWorker` instance. You can achieve this in a variety of ways. One such suggestion would be to pass the reference to the class when instantiating it.

For example, since `GenBulkReceipts` is the class that instantiates `GenBulkReceiptsBLL`, then in the constructor for `GenBulkReceiptsBLL`, you could pass the instance of the `BackgroundWorker` that is currently being used in `GenBulkReceipts`. This would allow for you to call `ReportProcess(...)` directly. Alternately, you could pass the reference directly into the `Get_AccountsToBeReceipted(...)` method.

Comment: The GenBulkReceiptsBLL does not pick up Backgroundworker when I pass it directly into the public DataSet Get_AccountsToBeReceipted(DataSet dsImport, BackgroundWorker worker). Also when I pass the instance of BackgroundWorker to the GenBulkReceiptsBLL constructor. I would appreciate a example if that is possible.

Comment: Sorry long day just needed the using reference

Comment: Not yet the progress bar still do not seem to progress

Comment: @user1171437 It could be helpful if you posted your modified code. But at a guess (and from the code above) I would guess the UI isn't getting time to update the visuals - hence no progress updates. You would need to allow the UI to update after each call to the progression method. The best way for this, would be to have the progress-moving operations occur on a separate thread.

Comment: How would I go about doing that

Comment: @user1171437 Actually, I forgot that the `BackgroundWorker` should be running asynchronously already. Have you put a break point on the line that updates the `ProgressBar` itself to make sure it is actually progressing?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass your `worker` to the `Get_AccountsToBeReceipted` method - it can then call [`BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx):

```
// In GenBulkReceipts
public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    DataSet importDataSet = e.Argument as DataSet;
    AccountsToBeImported =
         new BLLService().Get_AccountsToBeReceipted(importDataSet, worker);
}

// In GenBulkReceiptsBLL
public DataSet Get_AccountsToBeReceipted(DataSet dsImport,
                                         BackgroundWorker worker)
{
    ...
    worker.ReportProgress(...);
}
```

Alternatively, you could make `GenBulkReceiptsBLL` have its own `Progress` event, and subscribe to that from `GenBulkReceipts` - but that would be more complicated.

Comment: As in the above example public DataSet Get_AccountsToBeReceipted(DataSet dsImport, BackgroundWorker worker) Backgroundworker is not picked up same as the DataSet

Comment: @user1171437: It's not clear what you mean by "is not picked up".

Comment: Sorry long day just needed the using reference